# Attempting to use google.storage.sync.set inside google.runtime.onStartup has no effect

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension with the 'background' permission, meaning it continues running in the background even if the chrome window is closed. However, if the user ends chrome in the background as well, I want to reset some values in chrome.storage to default values. I thought creating a listener for the **onStartup** event would work, where I would then reset these values. However, this doesn't work. For whatever reason, chrome.storage.sync.set doesn't work properly in the callback of **onStartup**.

When checking the log, I always see 'Startup', therefore it's definitely running without a problem as far as I can tell, though if I later check the values they remain the same as before closing Chrome completely.

I've already checked through my code to see if the value is changed somewhere else but this does not seem to be the problem. To be certain I've tried commenting everything else out, but it still doesn't work.

Here is the code I have right now (it's in my only background.js file).

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        desc: '',
        timer: -1
    }, function () {
        console.log("Startup");
    });
});

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        desc: '',
        timer: -1
    }, function () {
        console.log("Installed");
    });
});
```

For clarity, here is an example inside my popup.js file where the value 'desc' is changed depending on user input. Whatever is written here is the value that remains even after **onStartup** has run, which is not expected:

```
i_text_pom.oninput = function() {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({desc: i_text_pom.value}, function () {
        console.log("Uus desc on: " + i_text_pom.value);
    });
};
```

I expected the storage variable 'desc' to be just an empty script, but once chrome has restarted it's still the same as before the full restart.

Comment: The currently posted code doesn't show where and how you write a different value so we can't tell what that means: "they remain the same as before".

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand. Could you elaborate exactly what sort of code I should post to help? As far as I understand, the code given shows that when the extension is installed, some key value pairs are set in the storage (desc: "", timer: -1) and then when Chrome is opened again, these values are changed back to what the default onInstall values were. I didn't post the code that changes these these values in, for example, the popup.js file, since I thought that be redundant. The desc value for example is changed based on an input field in the popup.

Comment: @wOxxOm Alright, I added an example of where the value 'desc' changes in my code.